# Why can VS 2008 find a custom tool in XP but not in Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, windows-xp

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows 7.

My company has a build tool that registers itself under the C# node.  More specifically it creates this entry in the Registry:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Generators{fae04ec1-301f-11d3-     bf4b-00c04f79efbc}\AssemblyName]

Other team members are running Windows XP, while I'm running Windows 7.  The tool works fine for them.  When I try and run the custom tool in VS 2008, however, I get a not found error.

I've pasted the rest of the registry changes below.  Why can Visual Studio find the tool in XP but not in Windows 7?

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Generators{fae04ec1-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}\AssemblyName]
"CLSID"="{ACD71775-E698-4CE2-9B59-C28E116E5394}"
"GeneratesDesignTimeSource"=dword:00000001
"GeneratesSharedDesignTimeSource"=dword:00000001
@="AssemblyFriendlyName"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AssemblyName]
@="AssemblyName"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AssemblyName\CLSID]
@="{ACD71775-E698-4CE2-9B59-C28E116E5394}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{ACD71775-E698-4CE2-9B59-C28E116E5394}]
@="AssemblyName"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{ACD71775-E698-4CE2-9B59-C28E116E5394}\Implemented Categories]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{ACD71775-E698-4CE2-9B59-C28E116E5394}\Implemented Categories{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{ACD71775-E698-4CE2-9B59-C28E116E5394}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="AssemblyClassName"
"Assembly"="AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a949dc6e405b4f5"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file://C:/Windows/Assembly.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{ACD71775-E698-4CE2-9B59-C28E116E5394}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="AssemblyClass"
"Assembly"="AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a949dc6e405b4f5"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file://C:/Windows/Assembly.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{ACD71775-E698-4CE2-9B59-C28E116E5394}\ProgId]
@="AssemblyName"

Comment: What about `file://C:/Windows/Assembly.dll`? Does this file really exist?
If this is your extension dll, perhaps try to place it in a different folder.

Are you using x64?

Comment: Yes, the file does exist.  Yes, the operating system is x64.

Comment: Tried changing the registry file to point to a different location (user directory) and copied the file there.  Still no go.

Comment: Tried building an x64 version, but no luck.  Is VS accessing the registry differently in 7 than in XP?

Comment: For some application Windows enables registry virtualization, that means that their registry accesses go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` but I doubt whether VS2008 SP1 is suffering from the issue. Besides, it would only affect the first two of the registry keys you mentioned, not the ones under CLASSES. Further note: Your dll must be appropriate to the VS you're using not to the OS. So if you use 32-bit VS you need to use a 32-bit assembly (or a cross-platform one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

The problem was that Windows 7/Vista has a different node for x86 applications running on them.

When I downloaded [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), I found that VS was looking under HLM\Wow6432Node\Software instead of HLM\Software.  This is created especially for x86 apps running in x64.  As soon as I added the entries to that node, everything worked fine.